# Django Annotation Custom Value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to add a new col `total_sum` to every object of `SomeModel`. To calculate it I try to use my  function `calc_total_sum` which requires `id` of the object and some external args.

```
SomeModel.objects.all().annotate(
    total_sum=Value(calc_total_sum(F('pk'), start_date, end_date), DecimalField())
)
```

But this query seems to be wrong because then my function receives not value of each pk but just a function `F`

How can I fix it?

Comment: I guess `calc_total_sum` is a python function ? If that's correct, then it's not gonna work. Annotation is something which you want to be calculated by your database thus, you need to express the `calc_total_sum` function via [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's python function. So can I add this new col via other approach using python function? Also I'd like to be able to sort this queryset by this new col. Or I have to convert queryset to `list` and work with it?

Comment: It really depend on the use-case: sometimes it could be calculated in python, but most of the time it is better to be calculated by the database, especially if you want to sort by this computation. What's the body of `calc_total_sum`, what is it actually calculating ?

Comment: Please share the details of the `calc_total_sum` function together with the relevant (parts) of the models.